# ElasticSearch - PHP - grab the last query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Is there any way of dumping the last run query in json format (or otherwise) in Elastic Search? Ideally while working with PHP Lib. (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php)

Comment: If you set the log level to DEBUG you should see the [request being sent](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/fb4cac7f7e7d0dec9aa1d62552ccfcb7c4ac1662/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php#L383) and the [received response](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/fb4cac7f7e7d0dec9aa1d62552ccfcb7c4ac1662/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php#L395) in the debug log.

Comment: @Val Can you add this an as answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the log level to DEBUG you should see the [request being sent](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/fb4cac7f7e7d0dec9aa1d62552ccfcb7c4ac1662/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php#L383) and the [received response](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/fb4cac7f7e7d0dec9aa1d62552ccfcb7c4ac1662/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php#L395) in the debug log.